# How can I enable silent automatic updates for Google Chrome?

Tags: upgrade, google-chrome, automation

Installing Google Chrome causes a third-party software source to be added from which Google Chrome upgrades can be retrieved:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

$ head -n 9 /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release
Origin: Google, Inc.
Label: Google
Suite: stable
Codename: stable
Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 04 Oct 2011 00:57:43 +0000
Architectures: i386 amd64
Components: main
Description: Google chrome-linux repository.

$ grep '^Package: ' /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages 
Package: google-chrome-beta
Package: google-chrome-stable
Package: google-chrome-unstable
```

How can I enable unattended upgrades from this repository?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1. Install unattended upgrades:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
   ```
2. Enable unattended updates on the Google Chrome repo by editing the unattended upgrades list and adding the Google Chrome repo in it:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
   ```

   Add `"Google LLC:stable";` to the allowed origins:

   ```
   Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
       "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-security";
   //  "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-updates";
   //  "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-proposed";
   //  "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-backports";
    "Google LLC:stable";
   };
   ```
3. Test

   Use `sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run` to test, if all came clear you should be having updates to Google Chrome installed without any intervention from you.

To check that it's working tail the log after the dry run:

```
cat /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log
```

and you should see something along the lines of this in your log:

> 2011-10-11 18:03:23,292 INFO Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=oneiric-security', 'o=Google, Inc.,a=stable']

You can change the configuration of the unattended updates by editing the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`, options for the configuration are in the `/etc/cron.daily/apt` script header. Read them to configure the frequency of the unattended updates.

Comment: As of October 2018, Google has changed the name of it's repository. Change the string from `"Google\, Inc.:stable";` to `"Google LLC:stable";`

Comment: for Ubuntu 18+ and newer Debian gksudo got deprecated and removed from the repos use i suggest to replace gksudo in this answer with ```sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades```

Comment: If you want to avoid having to merge conflicts when unattended-upgrades is updated (or reconfigured), you can create a new file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` that contains `Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern:: "origin=Google LLC";` instead (it just needs to sort later than `50unattended-upgrades` such as `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/google-chrome`).

Comment: how to find the origin pattern? here : https://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.com/2020/02/advanced-unattended-upgrade-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` and add a line inside `Origins-Pattern`:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
        // Keep existing content here, just add:
        "origin=Google LLC,codename=stable";                              
}
```