# How to enable silent automatic updates for any repository?

Tags: updates, automation

I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64318/how-can-i-enable-silent-automatic-updates-for-google-chrome) how to enable silent automatic updates for Google Chrome. However, I have other repositories like spotify, docky and others for which I would like to enable silent updates.

I am trying to do this in my Ubuntu 10.04 system. But this question applies to all Ubuntu versions. I have the **unattended-upgrades package** installed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want silent **security** updates. or ALL updates installed without intervention?  Why?

Comment: Pretty much all updates including the user repositories as well.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

First, install `gksu`:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

The easiest way of enabling unattended updates for your system is to edit the file `50unattended-upgrades` inside `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` with your favourite text editor, for example:

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

In it you need to comment out the commented sections of the `Allowed Origins` block.

Change:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

to:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-security";
        "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

---

For software that is not on the Ubuntu repos that you would like to update, you need to add an **origin** and **archive** to the file. To find what those are for your PPAs, open the folder `/var/lib/apt/lists/`, that is the storage area for state information for each package resource. What you are looking for is the files that end with ***Release*** in the name.

Open one with your text editor, e.g. for Google Chrome:

```
gedit /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release
```

Inside you will see something like the following:

```
Origin: Google, Inc.
Label: Google
Suite: stable
Codename: stable
Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2011 19:09:01 +0000
Architectures: i386 amd64
Components: main
Description: Google chrome-linux repository.
```

The origin is obvious (`Origin: Google, Inc.`) and the archive will be whatever is under the line `Suite` (`Suite: stable`).

If either `Origin` or `Suite` is missing, then they will be the empty string. But note that if *both* are missing, then probably it will not be possible to use that source with unattended upgrades without including other sources with the same issue.

After you noted those 2 lines, you need to edit the `50unattended-upgrades` file and add the lines using this format `"<origin>:<archive>";` of for this example's sake `"Google\, Inc.:stable";`.

Google Chrome's origin is kinda tricky, because it has a space, an end pointn and a comma in it, but most ***Release*** files will be easy to read.

As another example, [Node JS source](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) specifies an origin (`Node Source`) but not an archive; so you can match it with `"Node Source:";`.

*Allowed Origins* is matched using shell-style wildcards (more specifically, with Python's [fnmatch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html)). If you're careful enough to not include conflicting sources, it's possible to write things like `"Node *:*";`.

---

Do not forget to make a backup of your `50unattended-upgrades` file before editing it. Do that with:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.bak
```

To test the changes done on the file, you can use `sudo unattended-upgrades` with the parameters `--dry-run` and `--debug`.

- `--dry-run` will run an unattended upgrades cycle, except it will not really install the upgrades, only check and verify that everything is ok.
- `--debug` will enable verbose mode.

You can always check the logs for `unattended-upgrades` at `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`.

---

You can change the configuration of the unattended upgrades by editing the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`. Options for the configuration are in the `/etc/cron.daily/apt` script header. Read them to configure the frequency of the unattended upgrades.

Comment: Thanks...Very detailed! may i ask why you put a \ after Google?

Comment: Because of the special characters in the origin, its an escape character for the comma. Most origins you find will not have that.

Comment: Added more information on how to test and configure.

Comment: libreoffice's PPA has Origin: LP-PPA-libreoffice and suite: lucid. Does that mean I need to do "LP\-PPA\-libreoffice:lucid" ?

Comment: No, `-` are ok on the origin or archive. Give it a test with `sudo unattended-upgrades --dry-run --debug` when you are done.

Comment: "LP-PPA-libreoffice:lucid"; should be the line to add.

Comment: @BrunoPereira a specific example on how to get that from PPA sources in the answer would make it perfect!

Comment: @JorgeCastro what do you mean, remove the chrome example and add a libre office or a way of reading the release file directly from launchpad?

Comment: @Bruno You can reference the Google one since you've already written that up, I would expect that most people would want this for PPAs though no? Shrug.

Comment: To add to Bruno's answer, I didn't use a back slash before that comma and it works just fine. ~ $ head /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades // Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins { "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security"; "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates"; "Google, Inc.:stable" // "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed"; // "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports"; };

Comment: I had to run a sudo apt-get update before the unattended-upgrades script (with --dry-run and --debug) would detect any upgrades from my custom repository. Isn't that odd?

Comment: @jos No, that is the way it works, `--dry-run` will check if on the updated lists there is any updates available and output them to you, the lists updates via whatever is your configuration in `/etc/cron.daily/apt`, running it manually does not update the lists I think.

Comment: Is it possible to append to Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins, or override it with another config file? I have some locally-maintained dev packages, and I want to override unattended-upgrades for everyone, but without clobbering existing config files.

Comment: What should I put as the archive name when the corresponding Release file doesn't list a Suite?

Comment: Can you give an example on this?

Comment: If there is no Suite in a Release, then you can put an empty string as the Suite and it will match, e.g. `"Rackspace:"` (tested with `unattended-upgrades --dry-run --debug`).

Comment: Please also check the automated approach here: http://askubuntu.com/a/792621/417607

Comment: @Bruno Pereira Sometimes the origin is url, should that be avoided.

Comment: What if _Origin_ or _Suite_ are not present?

Answer (score 14):

Automated approach for @Bruno Pereira's answer:
**(Please consider starring the github repo if you find the answer useful.)**

Code Link: https://github.com/abhigenie92/unattended_upgrades_repos

- Check repositories to add:

  ```
  $ python automatic_upgrade.py 
  Add repos:
  "Ubuntu:xenial";
  "LP-PPA-kubuntu-ppa-backports:xenial";
  "LP-PPA-tuxonice:xenial";
  "LP-PPA-webupd8team-sublime-text-3:xenial";

  Skipping files due to not present origin or suite. Or origin being a url.:
  packagecloud.io_slacktechnologies_slack_debian_dists_jessie_InRelease
  tiliado.eu_nuvolaplayer_repository_deb_dists_xenial_InRelease
  ```
- Now edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` to include them:

  ```
  // Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
  Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
    "Ubuntu:xenial";
    "LP-PPA-kubuntu-ppa-backports:xenial";
    "LP-PPA-tuxonice:xenial";
    "LP-PPA-webupd8team-sublime-text-3:xenial";
  };
  ....
  ....
  ```
- Check to see if they are included:

  ```
  $ sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run --debug
  Initial blacklisted packages: 
  Initial whitelisted packages: 
  Starting unattended upgrades script
  Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-proposed', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial', 'o=LP-PPA-kubuntu-ppa-backports,a=xenial', 'o=LP-PPA-tuxonice,a=xenial', 'o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-sublime-text-3,a=xenial']
  pkgs that look like they should be upgraded: 
  Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                  
  fetch.run() result: 0
  blacklist: []
  whitelist: []
  No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
  ```

Comment: @andy.holmes welcome, please consider starring the github repository if possible. Link- https://github.com/abhigenie92/unattended_upgrades_repos

Comment: You may also wish to modify how dpkg treats packages that attempt to modify configuration files: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138751/unattended-upgrades-and-modified-configuration-files/

Comment: This python script is excellent, however I had to modify what README.md suggested for 50unattended-upgrades for my Raspberry Pi running stretch. Specifying the allowed origin as, e.g., `"Raspberry:stable";` didn't work. Instead I used, e.g., `"o=Raspberry, a=stable";`

Answer (score 11):

Editing `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, add the following:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
        "origin=*";
};
```

This will allow unattended upgrades for all packages.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clear and concise answer. But there are packages which have `origin:''`, for example datadog-agent from `site:'apt.datadoghq.com'`.  In that case it would also be needed to add `"origin=";` to not skip packages with empty origin. But then it's better to just use `"site=*";` instead of `"origin=*";`.

Comment: I have added my own repository into a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/my_repo.list`, but it don't upgrade the package. Manually it works with `sudo apt update`. Any clue how?

Comment: Does this use the same sources as a manual update, i.e. does it ignore disabled sources?

Answer (score 3):

There are instructions for forcing a rerun to make cron start the automatic update at the following [link](http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Enable_Automatic_Updates#Forcing_a_rerun_to_test_cron_working).
The procedure to stop cron is this

```
sudo service anacron stop
sudo service cron stop
sudo rm -rf /var/run/unattend* /var/run/cron* /var/run/anacron*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/periodic/*
```

and to restart cron to make the automatic update happen now (or at least within a few miutes) is

```
sudo service cron start
sudo anacron -fn
```

**How it works**

Several things will trigger it to run.

- It is fired off from the running of `/etc/cron.daily` by cron, specifically `/etc/cron.daily/apt`. Cron runs `/etc/cron.daily` at 6.25 am (see `/etc/crontab`)
- Anacron runs from upstart? and it will fire off `/etc/cron.daily` after 5 minutes of uptime (see `/etc/anacrontab`)

  Note `APT::Periodic::RandomSleep` can be set in
  `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`, but defaults to 1800s (30 mins) so no
  updates may happen till 30 mins after `/etc/cron.daily/apt` runs.

**Log**

If it works things should get logged in this folder, `/var/log/unattended-upgrades`.

Comment: This was especially useful to me as my virtual hosting provider thought it would be a good idea to remove ``/etc/cron.daily/apt`` from the default Ubuntu 12.04 installation - so automatic APT updates were not taking place :-(.  The ServerFault answer http://serverfault.com/a/568329/95570 provided details on getting that file re-created.