# How can I check if automatic updates are enabled and disable them if they're enabled?

Tags: server, updates

I want to be sure if automatic updates are enabled on Ubuntu 12.04 server.

How exactly can I check this?

And how can I disable automatic updates if it's enabled?

Comment: I am trying to build a server that is configured the same as others, and would really love it if somebody answered the simple questions, How can you check if auto updates are enabled... I understand how to turn them on and off relatively well... but would like to just know the status.

Comment: The original question was about 'updates', but answers make reference to 'upgrades' whilst including the word 'update' in that same context. Whilst I note that my Software Updater does my manual updates OK it also offers an upgrade to a later major release of Ubuntu. There seems to be great confusion in the use of the two terms from many sources.

Comment: "Update" and "upgrade" have several meanings; I don't think restricting them is feasible. For example, [touch(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/touch.1.html) uses "update" to mean something not directly related to package management: "Update the access and modification times of each FILE to the current time." Ubuntu's Software & Updates utility and `apt-get update` mean different things by "update." I think [this ship has sailed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/that_(or_the)_ship_has_sailed). There's [a meta post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17228) though.

Comment: To check if Unattended Updates are enabled I found the following answer the most helpful: https://askubuntu.com/a/1108745/1130956

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There is a package that can be used to do this for you.

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
```

or if unattended-upgrades already installed. Or you can checkout the [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates)

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades
```

That is the package you need to install. Once its installed edit the files

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

In that file you can set how often you want the server to update.

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

The file should look like that. The 1 means it will update every day. 7 is weekly.

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

This files will let you chose what updates you want to make by choosing where apt can search for new updates and upgrades. ( My personal opinion on this is I would set it to security if this is a server )

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";

};
```

The variables `${distro_id}` and `${distro_codename}` are expanded automatically. I would comment out the updates entry and just leave security.

Comment: Should this be updated to mention `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` as this is where `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";` and `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";` are kept by default on 13.10?

Comment: also, on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS the `50unattended-upgrades` file already has *only* security updates set, so that default seems correctly set there and the file should not need to be edited.

Comment: In my fresh ubuntu server, there is no `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` in there. There is `unattended-upgrades` package already installed and `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` is there too. My question is, I manually added `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` and should I reboot my server so the configuration will take effect?

Comment: This appears to be a guide on how to install and setup unattended upgrades, not how to assert upgrades are applying.

Comment: Thanks, mine was outdated for some reason after upgrading to 17.04.

Comment: When exactly do these updates get installed? I mean they can get installed once a day, once a week, etc, but at what time of day? Wouldn't just getting the update not be enough if that program was already running? It would just keep using the version it previously had running unless you reboot the program or the computer right?

Comment: Let's say I changed this this to 0: APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0"; How do I manually check what 'unattented-upgrades' are available at the moment?

Comment: @foresightyj you do not need to add `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` if you have `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` whose settings would override the settings made in the former one. The former file may be generated by `update-notifier-common` package, if you have it installed.

Answer (score 29):

Check the logs at `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/` to verify that your unattended upgrades are being applied.

Comment: While I upvoted your answer, its the closest answer to what I need (currently), can you explain what I would want to look for? What does it look like if its enabled vs disabled! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

(I made another answer, because my changes to LinuxBill's answer were rejected.)

There is a package that can be used to do enable automatic updates for you. It is called unattended-upgrades.

Use the following command to enable/disable automatic updates:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades
```

That command will modify file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` and may also modify `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`.

Alternatively you can enable automatic updates GUI way by `software-properties-gtk` in the Updates tab by changing setting in "When there are security updates:". That will modify files `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`.

Alternatively you can modify the aforementioned file(s) manually. EDIT: You could create a new file with greater number as name prefix (say 21auto-upgrades) to override the settings done in 20auto-upgrades.

In that file you can set how often you want update be called:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

The 1 means it will update every day. 7 is weekly. Variable APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval determines how often  "apt-get autoclean" is executed automatically. 0 means disable for these variables, so that way you can disable automatic updates and removes. EDIT: as now automatic updates and upgrades are called using Systemd timers and services rather than Cron, it is best to set the variables to "always" rather than "1". That way the changes will be get even if partly randomized timing makes the call to be done somewhat sooner than a full day after previous call.

You can check the current settings by `apt-config dump APT::Periodic`

You can change the way unattended upgrades work by editing file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. This file will let you choose what updates you want to make by choosing where apt can search for new updates and upgrades. Actually, it is better to create a new file where you put the modifications; name it as `51unattended-upgrades-local` or something else greater than the original file in the directory so that the changes will be effective; that way the original file remains unchanged which helps if upgrading unattended-upgrades implies changes to the file.

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

The variables `${distro_id}` and `${distro_codename}` are expanded automatically. In above only security updates are done automatically. You can extend automatic updates to any repository and do settings in `Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern` section. See [another question](https://askubuntu.com/q/87849/21005).

You may want to change

```
//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "false";
```

to

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";
```

That will automatically remove e.g. excessive old kernels so that /boot does not become full. It is equivalent to `sudo apt autoremove`.

EDIT: Newer versions of unattended-upgrades include more sophisticated settings for removing unused packages so you don't need to enable the previous setting:

```
// Remove unused automatically installed kernel-related packages
// (kernel images, kernel headers and kernel version locked tools).
//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";

// Do automatic removal of newly unused dependencies after the upgrade
//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-New-Unused-Dependencies "true";
```

There is more information in [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) and [unattended-upgrades github](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades)

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades` made the `20auto-upgrades` file

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and newer, Unattended Upgrades is already included with every stock install of Ubuntu (except Ubuntu Core, of course -- it doesn't use deb packages).

You can test for it several ways:

1. Check the timer status. Unattended Upgrades uses the `apt-daily-upgrade.timer`. In this example, you can see that Unattended Upgrades ran 39 minutes ago.

```
me@my-system:~$ systemctl status apt-daily-upgrade.timer 
● apt-daily-upgrade.timer - Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Sun 2021-12-05 05:41:07 CST; 39min ago
    Trigger: Sun 2021-12-05 06:20:41 CST; 1s left
   Triggers: ● apt-daily-upgrade.service

Dec 05 05:41:07 my-system systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
```

2. Check the completion timestamp. Unattended Upgrades timestamps a file after each successful run.

```
me@my-system:~$ ls -lh /var/lib/apt/periodic/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  2 17:42 download-upgradeable-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  5 06:21 unattended-upgrades-stamp    <----------
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  2 17:42 update-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  2 17:41 update-success-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  5 06:21 upgrade-stamp
```

3. Check the log. Unattended Upgrades are logged.  In this example, you can see that U-U ran properly. No upgraded packages happened to be available during this run. This is the most common result -- upgraded packages don't appear every day

```
me@my-system:~$ tail /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log

2021-12-03 08:30:20,578 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2021-12-03 08:30:25,854 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
2021-12-05 06:21:11,517 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2021-12-05 06:21:11,528 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=impish, o=Ubuntu,a=impish-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=impish, o=Ubuntu,a=impish-updates, o=Google LLC,a=stable, o=UbuntuESM,a=impish-security
2021-12-05 06:21:11,529 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2021-12-05 06:21:11,530 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2021-12-05 06:21:15,645 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

Comment: Thanks, this one actually answers the question, regarding how to tell if the unattended upgrades are enabled or not.  Also works on Ub 20.04

Comment: `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade` should still be non-zero in order to get upgrades done. I think value `"always"` is best now that calling unattended-upgrades is handled by Systemd timer, not by Cron.

Answer (score 2):

With Ubuntu 20.04 you can use

```
systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service
```

to check if the *unattended_upgrades* service is running.

Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-keep-ubuntu-20-04-servers-updated

Also to check logs of the unattended-updrades service use journalctl command:

```
# For the current boot logs
journalctl --unit unattended-upgrades.service --boot

# For all time logs
journalctl --unit unattended-upgrades.service
```

For more details see manual pages for the corresponding commands:

```
man systemctl
man journalctl
```

Comment: `sudo` is not needed.

Comment: Automatic upgrades may still be disabled even if _unattended_upgrades service_ is running.

Answer (score -2):

Automatic Updates are enabled by default.  If not, to enable automatic updates, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
```

In server, you can also you can edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, and comment out update update you don't want to upgrade automatically.  These edit must be done with root privileges.

Comment: I don't think that's turned ON by default, at least not on a server installation. However, it looks like the package is indeed installed automatically even on servers.

Comment: I concur. And as another commenter notes in https://askubuntu.com/questions/172524/how-can-i-check-if-automatic-updates-are-enabled#comment1608978_732862 , the presence of and contents within `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` is what actually enables auto-updating. Good to know!