# How can I stop the updates notifier box from appearing?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

#### note to future users who come across this question

this question has been tagged as a possible duplicate of

- [How can I check if automatic updates are enabled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172524/how-can-i-check-if-automatic-updates-are-enabled)

That question is about the whole process of having the OS `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` packages automatically - not the popup manager window.
However this question is a duplicate of this:

- [How to disable the update manager popup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218755/how-to-disable-the-update-manager-popup)

It turns out the update manager popup cannot be managed through apt's configuration files, it acts as an independent daemon and needs to be managed separately.

---

Every morning when I log into my install of `Ubuntu 16.04.1` I get this:

[image]

I don't want this box to appear, as I would rather handle the updating process manually.

I have the following configuration:

file: /etc/apt/conf.d/10periodic

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
// Try and turn off autoupating
APT::Periodic::Enable "0";
```

file: /etc/apt/conf.d/20auto-upgrades

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

#### My attempt to discover what is responsible for firing the automatic update system

`man apt.conf` states:

> PERIODIC AND ARCHIVES OPTIONS
>          APT::Periodic and APT::Archives groups of options configure behavior of
>          apt periodic updates, which is done by the **/etc/cron.daily/apt** script.
>          See the top of this script for the brief documentation of these
>          options.

It looks like this has been replaced by `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat` which mixes times abit so everyones Ubuntu doesn't try update at once then it calls:

```
/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily
```

`/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily` is a shell script that starts with a comment:

> This file understands the following apt configuration variables:
>    Values here are the default.
>    Create /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic file to set your preference.

so following this advice I entered this

```
    // Try and turn off autoupating
    APT::Periodic::Enable "0";
```

into `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` as you can see from my config listing above. yet I am still getting the notification...

Possible solutions I can think of

- the comment `// Try and turn off autoupating` may be causing a parse error of the config file, causing apt to ignore the entire file?
- unlinking or commenting out `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat` ?

How can I disable the update notifier box?

Comment: @DKBose thanks for pointing that out. have you noticed any problems associated with killing the update notifier daemon?