# I think I'm not notified of updates unless I manually do "apt-get update"

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates, kubuntu

I think I'm never notified of updates (with a systray icon) unless I manually do `apt-get update`. Is that normal? How can I make it check automatically?

In `software-properties-kde` I have "Check for updates: Daily"; "Install security updates without confirmation". So maybe it has been installing security updates all along, ones that don't require a restart, and I haven't know about it. But the several times (over a few months) that I've manually "refreshed", the "Install security updates without confirmation" thing didn't apply, probably because it applies only when the auto-updater finds updates. So, considering my settings, am I safe (i.e. can I trust that my settings will install security updates automatically)?

**Related question**: "[How can I check if automatic updates are enabled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172524/how-can-i-check-if-automatic-updates-are-enabled)" (but that question is about automatic update **installing** while I just want automatic update **checking**.

Comment: What are the setting in the lower part of of *System Settings > Software & Updates* (a. k. a. `software-properties-gtk`) *> Updates*?

Comment: It's hard to tell without further info. You'd have to wait for a security update to be published and then until the next day (give the system enough time to actually trigger a package upgrade; daily Anacron tasks are executed with some delay after boot/resume) and check whether it was installed or considered for installation. The output of `apt-cache show <PACKAGE> | grep ^Priority:` will reveal security updates and `/var/log/apt/history.log` shows past Apt operations.

Comment: Alternatively you can run the relevant Anacron task in `/etc/cron.daily` manually when you know there's a security update available and thus investigate the matter.

Comment: Or you can even revert a package to an earlier version that was superseded by a security update and then run relevant Anacron tasks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Kubuntu 16.04 release notes](http://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-16-04-lts-release-anouncement/) there is an option of two download managers:

> - Our new software center: [Plasma Discover](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/plasma-5-9-update-now-available-kde-neon) brim-full of software to choose from.
> - Keen developer types and friends of Muon Package Manager will be delighted to know that the project has got a new team of maintainers,
>     and a new release just in time for this Kubuntu LTS.

You should try to configure the download manager to update daily

Comment: @StefanMonov - sorry, My original answer was for Ubuntu, I've updated my answer for Kubuntu.