# Using unattended-upgrades or cron for automatically updating packages from different sources?

Tags: updates, cron, xbmc, automatic, unattended-upgrades

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 + XBMC on a HTPC and now I want to setup automatic updates on this machine.

On top of the normal Ubuntu sources, I have also 3 other sources installed, of which I want to receive automatic updates:

1) The XBMC ppa (http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu/)

2) The Steam source (`http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam`)

3) The Flirc source (`http://apt.flirc.tv binary/`)

I have already read about the unattended-upgrades package, but I don't know how to modify this package to also download updates for XBMC, Steam & Flirc (I've read something about reading the lists file in `/var/lib/apt/lists`, but unfortunately, I couldn't find `Source` and `Origin` defined in these lists).

Or is it better for me to go the `cron` route for this?

Comment: It's actually a continuation on that. I first followed the instructions from that question, but looking through /var/lib/apt/lists, I couldn't find a "source" and "suite" for Steam, XBMC and Flirc and now I'm not sure if unattended-upgrades will also upgrade these packages.

Comment: This should work: If you write a bash script with something like `echo PASSWORD | sudo -S apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` and then make a CRON job out of it.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was planning on doing, before reading about unattended-upgrades... Now, it's just a way of disabling unattended-upgrades and switching over to a cron job...

Comment: I have the Steam repository enabled, this is my Release file for it: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7849735/ So we have an Origin, and are missing a suite, which can be taken to be `precise`, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you can't find the Release file in `/var/lib/apt/lists` even after `sudo apt-get upgrade`, you can take a look at the file at the repository itself. In this case, they are:

1. http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release for XBMC
2. http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/Release for Steam and
3. Unfortunately, the Flirc repository doesn't do directory listing, so I can't locate it without more information.

The Origin values are present for both XBMC and Steam (`LP-PPA-team-xbmc` and `Valve Software LLC` respectively). The Suite in this case would be which ever folder under the `dists` section of the repository you are using (http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists or http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu/dists) - should be `precise` for for Steam and and `trusty` for XBMC PPA.

Comment: Allright, thanks! For the Flirc repository, it does have directory listing if you go to http://apt.flirc.tv/arch/, but they appearantly don't have a "release" file...

Comment: Also, just to be clear: I add "LP-PPA-team-xbmc, trusty"; and "Valve\ Software\ LLC, precise"; to the 50unattended-upgrades file, under Allowed Origins, right?

Comment: @TimoVerbrugghe I think you don't need to escape spaces, and the format is `Origin:Suite`, so you need to put a colon and not a comma between them.

Comment: My bad, I thought you did have to escape spaces, as was explained in the answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87849/how-to-enable-silent-automatic-updates-for-any-repository

Comment: Yes, but this comment says it works without spaces: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87849/how-to-enable-silent-automatic-updates-for-any-repository#comment207493_87854 Could you test with both?

Comment: Just did a dry run (and debug) with both, with the escape spaces, it shows "o=Valve\\ Software\\ LLC" with escaped spaces and "o=Valve Software LLC" without escaped spaces, so will probably use without ;).

Comment: Now, next obstacle: I know you can edit the preferences for unattended-upgrades by editing the 10periodic file, but if I want to change the time at which this is run, I need to change crontab for the cron.daily file, right?

Comment: @TimoVerbrugghe Excellent! Could you suggest an edit to that answer about escaping, since it is a popular answer? For setting the time, since it is a `cron.daily` script, you will have to change `crontab`. The unattended package doesn't offer a delay, only a possible reboot time, I think.

Comment: Allright, all set to go! Never mind about the escaping spaces, I read the answer wrong: you need to escape commas, not spaces. Thank you for all the advice! Now enjoying a fully automatically updated HTPC (well.. except for flirc... gonna ask the creator for a source and suite)