# Which is actual difference between package update and security updates?

Tags: apt, updates, lubuntu, security, unattended-upgrades

This is probably a real noob question...

I would like to understand what the "updates" alerts I get when logging onto my Lubuntu box actually mean.

When I read:

```
35 packages can be updated.
22 updates are security updates.
```

I understand that there are 22 security updates and 13 "regular" updates, for a global count of 35 updates.

As I want to run only security updates, I run:

```
sudo unattended-upgrade
```

But after that, I do not get any update notification any longer until the next updates cycle, so all the packages, security and not security, seem to be updated.

This seems also confirmed with:

```
sudo /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available
```

Which replies with a blank output.

Someone can explain? Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of your /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades file?

Answer (score 2):

1. The security updates are updates that fixes security bugs that can compromise the system, the rest are updates of improvement that fixes non-critic bugs or adds new features to a program. However, its recommended to install all updates.
2. When do you see this:

   ```
   35 packages can be updated.
   22 updates are security updates.
   ```

   Yes, you think correctly, there is a total of 35 updates, 22 of which are security updates, and the rest are normal updates.
3. `unattended-upgrade` upgrades **all** packages, in the `man` page says this:

   > automatic  installation  of security **(and other)**
   >      upgrades

   You can test this running `man unattended-upgrade`

Comment: Well, no, unattended-upgrades come by default to only upgrade security packages in Ubuntu, if you read its configuration file you will see that. More info here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87849/how-to-enable-silent-automatic-updates-for-any-repository +1

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to quote the man page:
"unattended-upgrade - automatic installation of security (and other) upgrades"

*and other* - it's going to do the lot...

The difference is that security upgrades are deemed important for security - so things like vulnerabilities in programs - & the others are just upgrades to a program with no bearing on security.

The point being, security ones should be done rapidly, the others aren't as important - but, if you avoid them, your system will become less up-to-date & eventually something will probably break. If you carry on as you are, you'll be fine.