# How to upgrade specific package using unattended-upgrades?

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I would like to configure auto update some packages using unattended-upgrades. But I couldn't find the why to specific only the packages I want. The /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades file have a Blacklist and Allow-Origin option which update all packages.

Is there any way to update only needed packages.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could make a cron job of command `apt-get install pkg`  where `pkg` is the package you want to update.

If you want to upgrade all packages in a certain repository, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/87849/21005).