# Why there is no option to enable silent automatic updates of Ubuntu, apps and PPA?

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

Apple MacOs, Android and MS Windows have the ability to do all system updates and applications silently. Ubuntu can do security updates silently and allows us to do for softwares too, but we have to modify the system by working with the terminal and know the right procedure, as here: [Silent updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87849/how-to-enable-silent-automatic-updates-for-any-repository) . However, Ubuntu does not allow to choose this possibility in its parameters, such as a simple checkbox: "Enable all updates of Ubuntu, softwares and PPA silently (Yes / No).

Why make this important task so difficult for non-expert users?

Answer (score -1):

Because updates can break your system/alter it's behaviour. If you don't have a clue how to edit some text files or about the terminal, you most likely don't know about recovery either. Also there is no need to update something that's not security critical if it works fine.

Comment: Any users can do the same updates when clicking on the update manager. The risk is the same as a silent method enabled by a checkbox in parameters. Reply not relevant for me.