# unattended-upgrades ignores Google Chrome upgrade

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, lubuntu, unattended-upgrades

I had posted this question earlier at serverfault.com, but no satisfactory response yet. Please forgive for posting here too.

My issue in short:

**unattended-upgrades** ignores Google Chrome upgrade.
A subsequent call of **apt-get upgrade** identifies and installs the upgrade.

What could be the reason?

*/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log:*

```
(...)
INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=focal, o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=focal-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=focal-infra-security, o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates  
(...)
```

Otherwise unattended-upgrade runs regularly and ok.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

My configs:

*/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades*:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

*/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades* (all commented lines taken out):

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
    "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
    "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
};
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
};
Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease "auto";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-WithUsers "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "08:00";
```

(Remark: A time lag between unattended-upgrades and apt-get upgrade is not the explanation because I had also manually started unattended-upgrades right before apt-get upgrade when I encountered the issue.)

Thanks for any help

bpn

Comment: Yes guiverc! Thanks and sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize (*we all miss things in searching*), especially no need to apologize twice.  Thank you @bpn for recognizing the duplicate & providing the answer yourself !

Answer (score 1):

Shame on me. I found the answer myself on askubuntu:
[How can I enable silent automatic updates for Google Chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64318/how-can-i-enable-silent-automatic-updates-for-google-chrome)
The allowed origins above don't include 3rd party sources.
So I added
"Google LLC:stable";
to the allowed origins in 50unattended-upgrades

Sorry again. I should have googled "unattended-upgrades in combination with "google chrome".

Comment: https://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.com/2020/02/advanced-unattended-upgrade-ubuntu.html